# Repeat keys stuck

Tags: keyboard, 22.04

using 22.04 3 LTS with an HP Envy 16 laptop (from last year).

I am having a problem with "Repeat Keys", where when i scroll around a document with the arrow keys they will very frequently get stuck and continue scrolling. This has happened with the up, down, left and right key on many occasions. This is even when turning the sensitivity with delay and speed down. No other keys are responsive at the point of one key getting stuck.

I have seen this or similar problems listed in many posts but never with an answer. I don't have this problem on the windows partition of my laptop, and the problem is always solved by rebooting (which presumably wouldn't work if the hardware was still sending a "left" or "down" signal). I generally avoid using repeat keys so i don't have to risk shutting down, so any advice to fix would be much appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT October 23 2023.
The issue completely disappeared for about a month. Then restarted after an update. Still never happens on windows partition. Clearly still affecting other users with similar problems, i.e. [Ubuntu 22.04 infrequent random key sticking on Dell G15 5521, that immediately clears on pressing a different key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446583/ubuntu-22-04-infrequent-random-key-sticking-on-dell-g15-5521-that-immediately-c)

EDIT November 23. Keys began getting stuck unbearably often recently after an update - was forced to reboot constantly. Booting into Xorg rather than Wayland seems to have resolved the issue (on the login screen, click the gear in the bottom right corner and select Xorg). I have had no recurrence after multiple days of using the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, with a DELL Vostro 15 3510.

I confirmed this is was not a notebook keyboard issue by using an external USB keyboard for some time. Then I switched to Xorg and had no problems so far.

So the interim solution is to run the graphical environment on Xorg only, as you did, too.